# localStorage not working to "save" game

Tags: javascript, html

Good day!

Complete JS noob here. I was following this tutorial: http://dhmstark.co.uk/incrementals-part-2.html regarding saving and loading the game. However, it is not working at all. I was hoping you fine folks might be able to easily tell me the issue with the code. There are no errors coming up on the browser console at all. But, when I re-load the page, it is not loading the "saved" data. I have tried putting the load() function within the js file itself, as well as including in the HTML header. I have also tried calling the load() function with a window.onload within the script itself.

Please help.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
  <title> Game </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function load() {
            var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
            if (typeof savegame.clicks !== "undefined") clicks = savegame.clicks;
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<button onClick="increment(1)"> Click </button>
<span id="clicks"></span><br /><br />

<button onClick="buyThing()"> Buy Thing </button><br />
Things: <span id="things">0</span><br />
Next Thing Cost: <span id="thingCost">10</span>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
```

### JS

```
//click tracker
var clicks = 0;

function increment(number){
    clicks = clicks + number;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};

//cursor
var things = 0;

function buyThing(){
    var thingCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, things));     //works out cost of this cursor
    if(clicks >= thingCost){                                    //check that player has enough clicks to afford cursor
        things = things + 1;                                    //increase number of cursors
        clicks = clicks - thingCost;                            //remove clicks spent
        document.getElementById('things').innerHTML = things; //update the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = clicks;   //update the number of clicks for the user
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,things));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('thingCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //updates the cursor cost for user
};


var save = {
    clicks: clicks,
    things: things,
}

//loop
window.setInterval(function(){
    increment(things);
    localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: instead of saving on interval , why not save only when the values change? at the end of the buyThing() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `save` object will be declared and defined only once and never be changed, so you will be saving over and over again the first initial value of the progress, you should save a newly object on each interval:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    increment(things);
    localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify({clicks: clicks, things: things}));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Awesome! This did the trick. For some reason it doesn't load the saved values until i actually click the "click" button or "Buy thing" button. But that's fine as I can figure that out as I go. Thank you so much!

Comment: perhaps code in main.js is the culprit. try submitting a live sample of your code on jsfidde/plunkr/codepen

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a reference issue.  The memory addresses of `clicks` and `save.clicks` are not pointing to the same thing, since it's a primitive number.

Putting all your game data into a single object will help reduce the global namespace pollution as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
  <title> Game </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("game")) || {
            clicks: 0,
            things: 0
        };
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<button onClick="increment(1)"> Click </button>
<span id="clicks"></span><br /><br />

<button onClick="buyThing()"> Buy Thing </button><br />
Things: <span id="things">0</span><br />
Next Thing Cost: <span id="thingCost">10</span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

JS

```
//click tracker
var game = load();

function increment(number){
    game.clicks += number;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = game.clicks;
};

//cursor
function buyThing(){
    var thingCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, game.things));     //works out cost of this cursor
    if(game.clicks >= thingCost){                                    //check that player has enough clicks to afford cursor
        game.things++;                                    //increase number of cursors
        game.clicks -= thingCost;                            //remove clicks spent
        document.getElementById('things').innerHTML = game.things; //update the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = game.clicks;   //update the number of clicks for the user
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,game.things));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('thingCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //updates the cursor cost for user
};

//loop
window.setInterval(function(){
    increment(game.things);
    localStorage.setItem("game",JSON.stringify(game));
}, 1000);
```